# Pack multiple .ts files into single bundle.js file

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, bundle

my code is like this:

Foo.ts:

```
export module Foo {

    export function load() { }
}
```

Bar.ts:

```
export module Bar {

    export function load() { }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "FooBar": ['./Foo.ts', './Bar.ts']
    },
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: ['[name]'],
        libraryTarget: "window"
    }
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The result however is, that only "Bar" becomes visible on the window object.
[image: FooBar]

If I switch the two paths of the FooBar entry point, than only "Foo" becomes visible. If I put both modules Foo and Bar into Bar.ts, also having ./Bar.ts as the last path of the entry point, than both modules become visble on the window object.
Some unintended overwriting or "the last one wins" behauvior is happening here.
How to achieve that both modules become visible on the window object without putting them into the same .ts file?

I originally included glob in my webpack.config.js, to have it as dynamics as possible:

```
var glob = require('glob');
...
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "FooBar": glob.sync('./*.ts*')
...
```

I would like to have all my .ts files become bundled into a single .js output file, but of course including all my modules.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is almost right and the entry array in solution works as expected. As mentioned in their [docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) it is used to *"inject multiple dependent files together and graph their dependencies into one 'chunk'"*. They just don't make very obvious that **only the last item in the array is actually exported**. See their last sentence [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#dynamic-entry).

For the solution in which you're using `glob` to work you'd have to pass webpack an entry object with a property or key value pair per file.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for pointing out, that I acually experience intended behauvior :D
Occording to your feedback, I came up with this:

FooBar.ts

```
import { Foo as _Foo}  from "./Foo";
import { Bar as _Bar} from "./Bar";

export namespace FooBar {
    export const Foo = _Foo;
    export const Bar = _Bar;
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "FooBar": './FooBar.ts'
    },
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        libraryTarget: "window"
    }
};
```

I am not 100% happy, because now I have to maintain FooBar.ts, but nevertheless the result is satisfying:

[image: FooBar]